# OUTER JOIN on 3 tables with a condition only present in the outer two

Tags: sql-server, outer-join

My output needs to be:

```
company, account, t1.status, t2.amount, t3.amount,
```

MS SQL Server

t1 has all the accounts but no company
t2 and t3 each have company field.
t2 and t3 eahc have amounts and some of the accounts appear in both tables while some only appear in one or the other

See table structure below:
[image]

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a0a6db/2) for the sample data and table structure.

Comment: How does Table1 relate to tables 2 & 3? Accounts don't seem to be specific to Companies... For example, account 10006 is listed as having a status of A; is that for company 10? 20? both? (you have that account for both companies; one in table 2, and a second one in table 3)

Comment: Hi. You give the output & input columns but don't say what output contents should be as a function of input contents or, alternatively, what the meaning of output & input tables are. And is your data input or output? Please read & act on [mcve]. Also hits googling 'stackexchange homework'--show what you tried. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Comment: @JoshPart Your textifying the images helps. (Although commenting to get the poster to do it is probably a better investment in the future.) But questions should be self-contained & what can be expressed by text in a post should be--including the text in your fiddle. Your edit shouldn't have been approved.

Answer (score 1):

If I understando correctly, you first need to have a `FULL OUTER JOIN` between t2 and t3 to get data from both tables, and `JOIN` that result with t1.

```
select tx.COMPANY, t1.ACCOUNT, t1.STATUS, tx.AMT2, tx.AMT3
from t1
inner join (select ISNULL(t2.COMPANY, t3.COMPANY) COMPANY,
                   ISNULL(t2.ACCOUNT, t3.ACCOUNT) ACCOUNT,
                   t2.AMT AMT2, t3.AMT AMT3
            from t2
            full outer join t3
            on t2.COMPANY = t3.COMPANY and t2.ACCOUNT = t3.ACCOUNT) tx
on t1.ACCOUNT = tx.ACCOUNT
```

This is the result obtained with your sample data (in you sample data only account 10005 shares company between t2 and t3)

```
COMPANY ACCOUNT STATUS  AMT2    AMT3
10      10000   I       50      NULL
10      10001   I       34      NULL
20      10002   I       230     NULL
20      10003   A       402     NULL
10      10004   I       120     NULL
10      10005   I       3       377
20      10006   A       4       NULL
10      10006   A       NULL    27
10      10007   A       33      NULL
20      10007   A       NULL    3828
20      10008   A       NULL    377
10      10009   I       NULL    77
10      10010   I       NULL    8818
20      10011   A       NULL    12
10      10012   A       NULL    33
20      10013   I       NULL    11
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `JOIN`?

```
Select t2.company, t3.company, t1.account, t1.status, t2.amount, t3.amount,
from [Table1] as t1
left join [Table2] as t2 on t1.account = t2.account
left join [Table3] as t3 on t1.account = t3.account
```

You can wrap company into one more `isnull` if you want to show that this account is not present in t2 and t3.

Comment: Yes, but I need the t2.company = t3.company when the account exists in both tables. How can I set this last condition?

Comment: You mean that for single AccountID companies in t2 and t3 can be different? And show only where it is the same?

Comment: I mean if they're both company 10 then show t1.amount and t2.amount for company 10.

Comment: And when t1.company is 10 and t2.company is 20 show two rows?

Comment: if the company/account exists in both tables, show 1 row. Another way to say it is that company/account is primary index on both t2 and t3.

Comment: Yes, but how should account 10006 appear? It has company 20 on table2 and company 10 on table3

Comment: This is clear. But what when it exists in both tables but with different companies? (See account 10006). What should be shown then?

Comment: If company/account combo only exist in t1 the t2.amount will be blank, and if it only exists in t2 then t1.amount will be blank. If it exists in both t1 and t2 then both t1.amount and t2.amount will be filled. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I updated my answer. Try it. But still, what if it exist in both with different company? Accouny 10006

Comment: If it exists in both with different companies then it's two different lines. COMPANY/ACCOUNT is the key. Thank you!